# Webscraping Data from Tradin View using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, algorithmic-trading, tradingview-api

I need to web scrape data from a trading view chart using an infinite loop, but I keep running into this error - StaleElementReferenceException.
I have tried making the program wait explicitly using the following function -

```
exceptions = (NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException)
def locate(path, type="xpath", time=5):
    global chrome
    global exceptions
    if type == "xpath":
        element = WebDriverWait(chrome, time, ignored_exceptions=exceptions).until(
            expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, path))
        )
    if type == "link_text":
        element = WebDriverWait(chrome, time, ignored_exceptions=exceptions).until(
            expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, path))
        )
    if type == "name":
        element = WebDriverWait(chrome, time, ignored_exceptions=exceptions).until(
            expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, path))
        )
    return element
```

Here is the full code that I have written:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

driver = "D:\\Repositories\\Bot\\chromedriver v89.0.4389.23.exe"
exceptions = (NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException)


def locate(path, type="xpath", time=5):
    global chrome
    global exceptions
    if type == "xpath":
        element = WebDriverWait(chrome, time, ignored_exceptions=exceptions).until(
            expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, path))
        )
    if type == "link_text":
        element = WebDriverWait(chrome, time, ignored_exceptions=exceptions).until(
            expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, path))
        )
    if type == "name":
        element = WebDriverWait(chrome, time, ignored_exceptions=exceptions).until(
            expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, path))
        )
    return element


def login():
    global chrome
    chrome.get("https://in.tradingview.com/chart/iVucV9D0/")
    chrome.maximize_window()
    locate("Sign in", "link_text").click()
    locate(
        "/html/body/div[11]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[4]/div/span"
    ).click()
    locate("username", "name").send_keys("myemail")
    locate("password", "name").send_keys("mypassword" + Keys.ENTER)
    time.sleep(3)
    locate("/html/body/div[6]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/form/button").click()


def buy():
    buyprice = locate(
        "/html/body/div[2]/div[5]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/span"
    ).text
    if buyprice != "n/a":
        return float(buyprice)
    else:
        return "na"


def sell():
    sellprice = locate(
        "/html/body/div[2]/div[5]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[6]/div[2]/span"
    ).text
    if sellprice != "n/a":
        return float(sellprice)
    else:
        return "na"


with webdriver.Chrome(driver) as chrome:
    login()
    while True:
        if buy() != "na":
            print("Supertrend Buy detected")
            # execute rest of the code
        if sell() != "na":
            print("Supertrend Sell Detected")
            # execute rest of the code
```

Can someone please help me?
PS: I am using python 3.9 and selenium version 3.141.0

Comment: Have you considered using scrapy ( https://scrapy.org/ ) instead ? Selenium is really supposed to be used for testing.

Comment: I am a new coder, I tried to use scrapy but couldn't figure out the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that a lot of these weird issues can be solved simply by downgrading to an older chromedriver and/or chrome/chromium, or switching to firefox/geckodriver. The range of compatibility between Selenium, the webdriver, and the browser is very narrow and unforgiving.

Comment: Can you direct me to which version of chrome driver to use?

Comment: if you google "selenium webdriver compatibility matrix" you will find a number of resources, many here on SO. unfortunately I don't have time to dig through my code right now.

Comment: just had occasion to revisit some code. what works: selenium 3.14.1, firefox-esr_60.9.0, geckodriver-v0.27.0.

I had too many problems with chrom{e,ium}, stopped using it with selenium many projects ago.

Comment: Would you please "accept" the answer? Thanks -- jc